# Background color doesn't work, even with !important

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

as for the context, yesterday, it was working fine and it would actually apply it on the section, but today, nothing is happening, and i just noticed it stopped working.

My javascript generate reports using a function that write the page's content using the data saved in a local json.
(see https://github.com/Mrcubix/Osu-PlayTime/blob/master/js/main.js)

I've tried moving it to a different element, adding !important like in the title, changing the values to make sure it wasn't working, created a new element in the index and noticed that it worked

as much as i try, section:hover doesn't apply a black layer on top of the image like it used to when hovering

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <title>Osu!PlayTime - Report</title>
        <link rel="styleSheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">    
    </head>
    <body>
        <section style="background-image: url('./bg/593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]/bg.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
            <p>593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]</p>
            <span>
                <p>Time played: 00:01:26.8</p>
            </span>
        </section>
        <section style="background-image: url('./bg/859608 LiSA - ADAMAS (TV Size)/bg.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
            <p>859608 LiSA - ADAMAS (TV Size)</p>
            <span>
                <p>Time played: 00:00:00.8</p>
            </span>
        </section>
        <section style="background-image: url('./bg/940746 CHiCO with HoneyWorks - Kimi ga Sora Koso Kanashikere/bg.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
            <p>940746 CHiCO with HoneyWorks - Kimi ga Sora Koso Kanashikere</p>
            <span>
                <p>Time played: 00:01:12.3</p>
            </span>
        </section>
    </body>


</html>
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial,Calibri,sans-serif;
}

section{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    margin: -1rem;
}

section:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

div{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}


div>p{
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding-left: 18rem;
}

div>div{
    flex-direction: row;
}

p{
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    padding: 6rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 1rem black ;
}
```

images used in the html:
[image]
[image]
[image]

another example (this time with images provided) for testing is available on this project github's repo:
https://github.com/Mrcubix/Osu-PlayTime/tree/master/example
or in a zip file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEuRx2vaexl-nlRyASNKMof2XHy1XG2p/view?usp=sharing

it is necessary to start a local http server in the project folder due to js limitations with loading local files, **main.py will run one if you have python**.

head to localhost:[port], (http://localhost:8000 in the case of my script)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: a reproducible example is already available in the question https://i.imgur.com/03yl1Mk.png it is ready to run if you have python installed or you can just run your own local http server

Comment: It might be reproducible, but it's not ***minimal***.

Comment: An external link to code is not compliant with the "reproducible example" guidance. From the linked page: "*Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself*" - meaning all the code necessary for the example should be on *this* page - those attempting to help you shouldn't have to follow to an external site.

Comment: in that case i cannot give a minimal, reproducible example as i would have to guess what cause the issue, which i tried to do already, which is also why i posted this question in the first place

Comment: Do you (just) mean, the background-image does not change it's oppacity when `:hover` the `section`?

Comment: section:hover isn't getting applied when hovering in the section.

section:hover is supposed to create a black layer  hover the image like it did i nthe beginning.

the example above is still bad as it will work for p even though i stated it doesn't work in the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use `position: relative;` and `absolute`

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial,Calibri,sans-serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

section::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
section:hover::before{
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
}

section p{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    padding: 6rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 1rem black;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/acIuq.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
  <p>
    593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]
    <span>Time played: 00:01:26.8</span>
  </p>
</section>
<section style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hhfu.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
  <p>
    859608 LiSA - ADAMAS (TV Size)
    <span>Time played: 00:00:00.8</span>
  </p>
</section>
<section style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ybVe.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
  <p>
    940746 CHiCO with HoneyWorks - Kimi ga Sora Koso Kanashikere
    <span>Time played: 00:01:12.3</span>
  </p>
</section>
```

Position the parent-element with `relative`, now you can add `position: absolute;` to the child-element. Or in this case - we use pseudo `::before` this creates an element between the opening-tag and the content (`::after` would create it after content and before closing-tag).

This needs an `content: '';` this could be nearly everything (...)
and position this to `absolute` with `left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;` to overlay it over the whole parent ( *= relative to the parent!*)

But now it also would overlap the `<p>` elements inside your `<section>`!
To prevent this, use `z-index`!
I gave the parent (`section`) the `z-index: 1;`, the overlay (pseudo-class `::before`) `z-index: 2;` and the `<p>`-elements (as children of `<section>`) `z-index: 3;`

So you have an order to layer your elements that are hovering each other!

Edit: Added transition 0.5s.
To make this work: give your element the standard that it should be normal (here: `opacity: 1;`) add the `opacity: 0.5;` to the `:hover` declaration. NOW you can use `transition: 1s` or what time you want the transition to be. It needs the opacity: 1; to the normal style, so it knows what is the starting-value on hovering. If you do this with for example `background-color` you have to give the normal-status to the element, even if it should be transparent! Only in this case "it" could know from where - to where it should do the transition (and back).

Comment: this would be perfect if i could also add transition: 0.5s but that doesn't seem to be possible unless i'm missing something cause afaik it doesn't work

Comment: c'mon.. just use a searchengine for a few minutes and try to learn :)

Comment: i've been doing this for 2 days now, a google search won't fix it if like blackground-color i tried every single way i know and are online, i have easily 20 result about it in my chrome history, i'm always doing research first before actually posting stuff, and those, i fixed your code so it actually doesn't have empty area, fixed various alignements issue related to the css and more, transitions has yet to be fixed

Comment: I updated my answer with descriptions and with the transition. 1 minute google "css opacity transition hover":  [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_fade1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_fade1)

Comment: that same website nor the 20 thread i went through doesn't state the fact two opacity tags are required, one for the starting (original) value defined in the element and one for the end value when the event is called.
 Even Mozilla's website doesn't state that. even that's not explained in your answer, you should had started with that in the first place if you wanted people to learn since most of them are probably struggling with half-made documentation, anyway, thanks part of the help i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have black layer then use:

```
section:hover {
    filter: brightness(30%);
}
```

You can't apply different background styles for hover state when this element has inline styles for background image - it won't override it. If you don't want my solution you can alternatively create pseudo-element before/after element which will cover his parent and then use background color.

Comment: this unfortunately, apply a layer in front of everything, which mean my text is also covered, the reason i want to apply a black layer behind my text is to make it more readable on top of these backgrounds.

as for your second suggestion, i tried applying it to my code except that cause the title and time played text to be displayed in column again, which is tried to fix but wasn't successful, (i also wasn't able to apply background-color nor brightness with this method)